# Jekyll Collection on Github, am I missing something

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm using jekyll on Github Pages to host a personal blog. Some posts have a series of pictures, and I'd like to use Collections as a simple photo gallery. I have created a collection directory and set up the collection within the config file. I have also told jekyll to output the collection files.

My goal is partially working on the post with images; I am successfully iterating over each item in the gallery and outputting a thumbnail. What isn't working is when you click on the thumbnail. What I want to happen is to have you go to the rendered collection page where the full-size image can be viewed and perhaps some additional context for that image.

When I click on the rendered collection page, I receive a 404, so I feel I'm missing something in the configuration or perhaps something with the collection itself. What I've read implies that this should "just work." A few sites have mentioned creating a custom layout, and you can see I've created a layouts folder and copied the contents of the minima theme pages layout into it.

Any help would be appreciated; please note Github Pages is hard set at jekyll 3.9.0, I believe.

Here are the links

- [repo](https://github.com/jeffpatton1971/kansaspattons)
- [post with images](https://jeffpatton1971.github.io/kansaspattons/blog/2009/10/18/pumpkin-patch.html)
- [config file](https://github.com/jeffpatton1971/kansaspattons/blob/main/_config.yml)
- [post file](https://github.com/jeffpatton1971/kansaspattons/blob/main/_posts/2009-10-18-pumpkin-patch.md)
- [collection file](https://github.com/jeffpatton1971/kansaspattons/blob/main/_gallery-2009-10-18/img58363.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same problem. Reason why the examples you saw online seem to work 'As is' is due to their naming convention which doesn't address pitfalls on broader use cases.

I fiddled at it for one full hour before i finally had the sense to cross check the URLs.

When you call `page.url` it gives you the location of the raw file in the directory's structure. however, the browser uses kebab case. so if your file resides in `staff_member/jane.md` it will use `staff-member/jane.html` instead. note the dash instead of underline.

Second, as you have just mentioned, the page url command doesn't provide the relative URL. example, if you are on github pages. the correct URL should be `https://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}/{filename}.html`. However, the page url command simply tags the filename to your baseurl, thats why you get a 404.

To tackle this, i found it to be more useful setting defaults in your config yaml file. like so:

```
collections:
 staff_members:
  output: true
  permalink: "/staff-members/:name"

defaults:
 -
  scope:
   paths: "staff_members/"
  values:
   layout: "staff"
```

The above config sets the permalink for each document inside the staff members collection, and uses the 'staff' layout for all the documents inside staff members collection folder. note the underline for directory structure and dash for permalink.

The lack of info online on Jekyll config online doesn't help at al, hope this post helps someone too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was guided to the solution I'm using from this thread I created on [talk.jekyllrb.com](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/github-pages-collections-output-404/7055). So basically, it was pointed out that the baseurl was missing from the generated collection link. I tried to force it via setting a permalink, but that did not work. Finally found the [relative_url](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) filter. Passing my URL through that filter fixed up the path issue. Github Pages uses basically a subdirectory (repo name), and so you need to add baseurl in the config, and then relative_url will fix up your links, so they work with the path.

> Relative URL
>
> Prepend baseurl config value to the input to convert a URL path into a
> relative URL. This is recommended for a site that is hosted on a
> subpath of a domain.

I'm unclear if I will need to change this once the site is migrated over from WordPress, but it's working for now.

Hopefully, this helps someone else.